# How to store array as key value pair in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array $result as follows

```
Array 
( [0] => Array ( 
[0] => Mr 
[1] => vinay 
[2] => hs 
[3] => tester 
[4] =>vinay.hs@abc.com 
[5] => 909099 
[6] => Yes ) 

[1] => Array ( 
[0] => Mr 
[1] => Suresh 
[2] => Kumar 
[3] => tester 
[4] => vinay.hs@abc.com 
[5] => 809090 
[6] => No ) 
).
```

I want to store this array as

```
Array
([0]=>Array ( 
[title] => Mr 
[firstname] => vinay 
[lastname] => hs 
[job_title] => tester 
[email] =>vinay.hs@abc.com 
[phone] => 909099 
[is_employed] => Yes ) 

[1] => Array ( 
[title] => Mr 
[firstname] => Suresh 
[lastname] => Kumar 
[job_title] => tester 
[email] => vinay.hs@abc.com 
[phone] => 809090 
[is_employed] => No ) ).
```

Explain me how to do this

Comment: is this $result array your own array or it's returned from mysql?

Comment: @Phelios asks because you might be able to get the row with `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: It has data retrieved from csv file

Comment: i update the answer to cater for csv file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$fp = fopen('foo.csv', 'r');
$fields = fgetcsv($fp); // assumes fields are the first row in the file

// or $fields =  array('title', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'job_title', 'email', 'phone', 'is_employed');

$records = array();
while ($record = fgetcsv($fp))
{
  $records[] = array_combine($fields, $record);
}
```

Obviously it needs error handling added to it.

Answer (score 3):

```
$newarray=array();

foreach($result as $res) {
 $a = array();
 $i = 0;
 foreach(array('title','firstname','lastname','job_title','email','phone','is_employed') as $key) {
  $a[$key] = $res[$i++];
 }
 $newarray[] = $a;
}
```

Comment: It's not working .the array $newarray is same as $result array

Comment: Try it now. It's ... as $key instead of $key => $arr

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = array("title" => "Mr", "title" => "vinay", "key" => "value")
```

access it with:

```
$arr["title"]
```

Comment: please explain me in depth.i did'nt understand

Answer (score 2):

```
array(
    array(
        'title' => 'Mr',
        'firstname' => 'vinay',
        'lastname' => 'hs',
        'job_title' => 'tester',
        'email' => 'vinay.hs@abc.com',
        'phone' => '909099',
        'is_employed' => TRUE
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Mr',
        'firstname' => 'Suresh',
        'lastname' => 'Kumar',
        'job_title' => 'tester',
        'email' => 'vinay.hs@abc.com',
        'phone' => '809090',
        'is_employed' => FALSE
    )
);
```

UPDATED:

My answer previously is dumb. If you are loading from CSV file, assuming the first element of array is the keys.

You might want to do something like this.

Sorry for my bad naming.

```
$keysArray = array_shift($arrayFromCSV);

$wantedArrayStructure = array();

foreach ($arrayFromCSV as $person) {
    $item = array();
    foreach ($person as $key => $value) {
        $item[$keysArray[$key]] = $value;
    }
    $wantedArrayStructure[] = $item;
}

var_dump($wantedArrayStructure);
```

Answer (score 0):

If, is is result from msql query. You should using function to get the expected result:

[mysql_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)